# How to initialize MEF ServiceLocator.Current?

Tags: c#, silverlight, mef

In my App.xaml.cs I have

```
private void InitializeContainer()
{
    var catalogs = new AggregateCatalog();

    var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    catalogs.Catalogs.Add(catalog);

    // Also adding Interactions project
    catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(InteractionsService).Assembly);
    catalogs.Catalogs.Add(catalog);

    // initialize the main application composition host (container) 
    CompositionHost.Initialize(catalogs);
}
```

However, when I try to get object initialized down a line like so:

```
this.InteractionsService = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IInteractionsService>();
```

I get exception that my ServiceLocator.Current is null.

How do I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing the call to `ComposeParts` or `Compose` in the set up of the `CompositionContainer` . Before you start to resolve instances via `GetInstance`.

There's an [MSDN walk through here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx), and some other samples [here](http://blogs.oosterkamp.nl/blogs/thomas/archive/2009/07/22/getting-started-with-the-managed-extensibility-framework.aspx) and [here](http://dailydotnettips.com/2011/09/04/working-with-compositionbatch-in-mef/). The relevant code snippet:

```
private CompositionContainer _container

//your code

var batch = new CompositionBatch();
batch.AddPart(this);

_container.Compose(batch);

//or more simply
_container.ComposeParts(this) //if this method is supported
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work this way. ComposeParts not available in Silverlight

Comment: @katit There's a 'Compose' in SL? I'll modify the answer with that approach if it might help.

Answer (score 2):

I had the very same question..

and found this which might be helpful,

http://www.itwox.com/post/Using-MEF-with-Common-Service-Locator.aspx

the key statement is

ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => whateveryourlocatorinstanceis );

Comment: Wayback machine is your friend: https://web.archive.org/web/20120125090930/http://www.itwox.com/post/Using-MEF-with-Common-Service-Locator.aspx